# Why do upvotes and downvotes have different weights with respect to reputation changes?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

When a post (question or answer) is upvoted, the poster gains 10 reputation. However, a downvote on that same post only costs the poster 2 reputation.

What is the reason for this difference?

I find this discrepancy particularly striking because it means that a 0-score post could have actually gained the poster a significant amount of reputation (e.g., 2 upvotes (+20) and 2 downvotes (-4) would mean a net gain of 16 reputation).

Comment: It is all part of the game ;)

Comment: Also, are you aware of [loss aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion)?

Comment: Also see [How Does Reputation Work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Answer (score 12):

Jeff Atwood, one of the site's founders, asked the question [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7322):

> When we started Stack Overflow, we wanted to make sure that downvotes were more of a visual and psychological motivator than a punitive action.

and in his accepted [self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763), declining his own feature request on the grounds that:

> Downvotes were always essentially cosmetic, with an extremely minor effect on reputation.

[Voting is, first and foremost, a *content rating* system.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437)

There are two consequences:

1. A downvote is not so much punishment, but a signal to *other users* that the post is not worth looking at.
2. Stack Overflow is largely moderated by the community (not just by diamond moderators and staff, who only get involved in exceptional cases). Community moderation depends on a system of earned [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), which are in turn based on reputation. Too much of a reputation penalty would decrease the number of users capable of moderating (this would have obviously been more of a concern in Stack Overflow's earlier days, but is still true on smaller Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: that is bull, so many higher rep get their Questions downvoted massively and the question isn't the cause, only spite

Comment: *That* claim is bull; almost no higher-rep users get their questions downvoted "massively" out of spite. Revenge downvotes do happen, but it is relatively rare, and it is generally reverted either by an automated script or by manual intervention. Some aren't caught, of course, or aren't worth the effort of invalidating, but we're talking about less than 3 votes here, generally on questions that are already "massively" upvoted. Everything this answer says is correct.

Comment: The quotes from Jeff summarize why I wouldn't mind seeing the downvote reputation penalty disappear, for casters and/or receivers, albeit with the awareness that many people would be reluctant to the change and that the technical effects (privilege-wise) and psychological effects (voting and posting behaviour) of the change are not well know.

Comment: i can't remeber how oftne i read of user with some rep, which do some moderation, get and they have the same problem as i, questions get downvoted, without any cause. so the common sense is, to make another account adn ask with thenew account, otheriwse you get them downvoted. no system will get them because a user in my case  only downvotes the question and then leaves, if you are clever you downbvote othe rquestions of the same user not on the same day, still wait some time, so no system will find you.

Comment: Another trick of downvoters is quite simply only down " at a time, the system will not detect it and you have to bither the mods with a flag to get it removed

Comment: @nbk Not sure I understood your use case, but even if it is more likely for curators to receive revenge downvotes, isolated incidents are not actionable. Occam's razor goes both ways. A single vote could have come from someone else by coincidence. Not to mention that whoever is wasting their time using downvotes as a weapon has quite some inner demons to face. Don't let them rustle your jimmies.

Comment: (Not to mention that indeed, the hypothesis that revenge downvotes are common is not proven without quantitative results, part of which we cannot really grasp.)

Answer (score 6):

From [the global Meta FAQ on reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/245360):

> Posts which are voted up increase their authors reputation; the reverse is true for posts which are voted down. Upvotes are **more heavily weighted** than downvotes.

Apparently the 'usefulness' of a question or answer to one person outweighs the 'unusefulness' to one other.

Comment: Makes sense, no? Example: I don't find any post about PHP particularly useful.