# Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?

Tags: support, faq, comments, downvotes, downvote-reason

Sometimes my post receives downvotes with no explanation on what I've done wrong. Even worse, sometimes I just get snarky comments!

It seems like this is especially bad for new users, who are made to feel unwelcome by veteran users. Stack Overflow's rules can be difficult to grasp, especially for newbies, and downvotes can feel hostile and discouraging.

Several ideas have been proposed for how to fix this, including:

- Every downvote should be accompanied by a mandatory comment
- Downvotes should be accompanied by a mandatory, *anonymous* comment
- Downvotes should be accompanied by a reason selected from a drop-down menu
- The *first* downvote should be accompanied by a mandatory comment
- Downvotes should cost reputation points unless accompanied by a comment
- …and other variations.

However, whenever someone suggests one of these changes on Meta, it gets unceremoniously rejected and (ironically) downvoted without a detailed explanation!

**Why are all of these ideas rejected?**

Is it because people here are *curmudgeonly trolls* who just hate people and don't *want* new users to feel welcome?

[image: Classic troll in the mountains, intimidating a boy with his horse]
<sub>[(Image source: "Norwegian Troll", by Ivar Rodningen)](http://avax.news/pictures/127383)</sub>

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: The other questions that talked about this haven't always been worded the best, and the reasons listed below have been scattered across various answers and comments. I like having a central canonical question that contains the common arguments and isn't adversarial in tone. I think this is a great idea for a resource that we can use as a better duplicate target.

Comment: Voting is meant to be 'friction-free'. Perhaps when someone offers a comment without having down-voted that fact could be marked somehow prominently on the comment. This might lessen the likelihood of retributive responses. (Probably suggested many times before now.)

Comment: By the same reasoning, we should require an explanation for every upvote. After all, if we have to explain why something is blatantly wrong or outright garbage, we should be equally able to explain why we think something is correct and useful for the community. TBH, I don't think that's the right direction.

Comment: The canonical is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*.

Comment: Ultimately, it's askers' responsibility to familiarize themselves with site standards; it's not downvoters' job to educate askers on this.

Comment: [reposted to MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/165773)

Comment: Due to repeated, excessive whining in the comments here about downvotes, which I just had to clean up *again*, I've been forced to lock the comments on this post permanently. This is why we cannot have nice things...

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Forcing downvotes to be accompanied by a comment sounds like a good idea at first blush, and many here would like to see new users get all the info they need to ask questions that are a better fit! Contrary to popular opinion, most users here are [kind](https://lifehacker.com/why-you-should-be-kind-instead-of-nice-1846124841) and want to help rather than enjoying "shooting down" newbies' questions with downvotes to make them feel bad and unwelcome. (In fact, that's not the purpose or intention of downvotes at all!)

What is not commonly understood or even immediately obvious to the casual observer is that Stack Overflow has become a big city. While big cities can offer tremendous benefits (for Stack Overflow, the analogy is a dense concentration of expertise), they also experience unique issues relating to the lack of resource scaling, including traffic, congestion, and pollution. In order to survive, big cities need different rules than small villages—and tend to feel more anonymous and harsh as a result. The importance of each individual diminishes, relative to the whole.

[image: A typical scene from a large urban area, showing dense traffic (cars) on the roads and pollution (smog) in the sky.]
<sub>[(Image source: Atta Kenare, Getty Images)](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/air-pollution-from-cars.htm)</sub>

[Downvotes are important for the health of the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting), and mandating comments for them would *massively* impede the way Stack Overflow currently works—to the point of potentially destroying it. It's just not feasible, for a number of very good reasons. That's why, although this gets suggested frequently (on average, 2–3 times per week), it is declined and often downvoted by the Meta veterans.

Here's an overview of the primary arguments for why it's a bad idea:

- **Downvotes are, first and foremost, a content rating system.** Rather than being a way of communicating with the *poster*, [they are a way of communicating to *future readers*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250181) that a question or answer is not interesting or useful. If someone wants to leave a comment to communicate with the poster, they can always do so, *independent* of the voting system.
- **In the vast majority of cases, nothing needs to be clarified.** The tooltip on the downvote arrow already explains what a downvote means, and it is specific for questions and answers. In most cases, the "comment" in the tooltip already adequately explains the logic behind the downvote, so an additional comment would just be wasted effort and noise.
- **Any requirement could be trivially circumvented** by entering gibberish or something non-constructive like "this is bad". Detecting and stopping those who enter such stuff through moderation/administrative action is simply not feasible on a site with millions of users.
- **It may not feel that way to you at the moment, but downvoters are doing the site a service, and making voting more difficult would impede the site's most important quality-control tool.** Voting is ad-hoc and frictionless *by design*! Voting separates good content from bad, and it makes the good content more visible. *This is essential for the platform to work, even if it sometimes feels mean.* If a vote is in error—which can always happen—the expectation is that the "swarm intelligence" of future viewers will eventually correct the problem. A single vote is nothing, really. What matters is the *sum* of all votes, which is why we only display the aggregate score.
- **Scale.** Stack Overflow gets some 12,000+ questions every day. Many of them are of poor quality or just not a good fit for the site. It is beyond human capability to respond to each one of those bad or misplaced questions with custom-tailored advice. It would drain too much time and energy from the unpaid volunteers who answer questions and help users.
- **If downvoting is made more difficult, then upvoting would need to be made correspondingly more difficult.** The system uses downvotes *and* upvotes to filter out the "good" content from the "bad." If consequence-free downvoting is a problem, then, logically, consequence-free upvoting is, too, because it potentially marks low-quality content as "good".
- **Documentation on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is made easily available for those willing to read it.** Stack Overflow's rules are special and arcane, but it's not like there hasn't been a lot written on the topic; even our #1 user, Jon Skeet has [written explanations](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) on how to ask a good question. Similarly, we provide [extensive guidance on how to answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
- **Leaving a comment accompanying a downvote can lead to negative consequences, like revenge downvoting and even off-site harassment.** Many experienced users [will tell you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353978) that they used to leave helpful comments along with their downvotes, but have stopped doing so because of the unpleasant blowback they received from unreasonable users. Even for those users who remain rational, commenting about votes almost inevitably leads to extended, off-topic discussions, which we strive to avoid.
- **Stack Overflow (the community, and the company) is actually doing a *hell of a lot* to make the place feel more friendly.** The past few years have seen tons of discussions, [initiatives](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), UI changes, [help center updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) and renovations, experiments like [mentoring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up/), and more—all aimed at making starting out at Stack Overflow a more pleasant experience without compromising on quality. Actually, a lot of veteran users feel that site's owners are putting *too much* emphasis on making the site feel nice, for the sake of traffic (which translates into money) over quality. Regardless of whether they're right or not, it is not accurate to say nothing is being done. It's just a really tough problem.
- **We can't accommodate everyone.** [There will always be more question-askers out there than there are competent answerers.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) You can't overburden the latter by allowing a huge quantity of bad or badly-fitting questions into the system—you'd destroy the entire system, and hence prevent any questions from getting answered. Not getting to ask your question on SO isn't a death sentence; many SO veterans have questions every day that they don't post on Stack Overflow because they know they wouldn't be a good fit in our Q&A model. The resources those veterans turn to in order to solve their problems are usually open to everyone on the Internet—they just take time, effort, and sometimes periods of frustration to understand. There are also other, more mentoring-oriented resources to turn to.

Comment: I'm now wondering if an automatic comment should be triggered on the first downvote pointing the user to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Maybe something like "It looks like your question could be improved, we suggest looking at the How To Ask page to improve it".

Comment: Personally, I do try to leave feedback when I think the OP can benefit, but keep that *specifically disconnected from voting*. I don't say *I downvoted because*, I just give the feedback to improve the post without saying anything about the voting. There is never a point in revealing how you voted, either way, in my opinion. If they start berating me for voting anyway, I can always fall back to "voting is anonymous, please don't assume that because I commented, I also cast a vote".